# How can I modify a vector inside a list?

Tags: r

I have a list containing three vectors, say:

```
test <- list(c(1,2,3,4),c(5,6,7),c(8,9,10))
```

I'd like to add elements to a given vector in the list. Let's say I'd like to add 11 to the last one (offset 3), so I'd have c(8,9,10,11) as the last element of the "test" list.

I tried:

```
test[3] <- c(test[3], 11)
test[[3]] <- c(test[1], 11)
test[3[length(test[3])] <- 11
append(test[3], 11)
```

And apparently nothing of the above works as I expect it to.
How can I do this?

Comment: `test[[3]] <- c(test[[3]], 11)`

Answer (score 3):

Extract one item with `[[`

The double square brackets are used to extract one element from potentially many. For vectors yield vectors with a single value; data frames give a column vector; for list, one element [text from here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2009/10/r-accessors-explained/)

after this use `c()` to concatenate:

```
test[[3]] <- c(test[[3]],11)
test[[3]]
```

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[3]]
[1]  8  9 10 11
```

Answer (score 1):

A `purrr` option (corrected by Ritchie's comment):

```
test |> purrr::map_at(3, ~ c(.x, 11))
```

Comment: I didn't give you the downvote but if you're suggesting a `purrr` option, consider `map_at()` rather than `map_if()` - `map_at(test, 3, ~ c(.x, 11))`.